# How to Update Django Model Relationship only with Foreign Key Value

Tags: django

I'm looking for a way to update a relationship on a model in Django by only passing the foreign key value and not the model being referenced in the relationship.

I understand that Django wants me to do this

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.get(id=2)
book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
book.update(publisher=publisher)
```

But I'm looking to just update the publisher using the publishers PK so something more along the lines of this.

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
book.update(publisher=2)
```

I have a significant amount of data that needs to get updated and I don't necessarily have a reference to what the model is for each field that needs to get updated on the "Book".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) here and work with `publisher_id`:

```
Book.objects.filter(id=1).update(publisher_id=2)
```

This will prevent first fetching the `Book` object with a different query, so normally this will run with a single query to the database.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway you can do an update with a dictionary? For example Book.objects.filter(id=1).update({publisher_id:2}) ?

Comment: @JamesParker: you can unpack the dictionary, so `Book.objects.filter(id=1).update(**{'publisher_id': 2})` (with two asterisks `*` in front of the dictionary).