# AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-3.8, django-3.2

I changed a OnetoOnefield in a PostImage model to a ForeignKey and getting the said error.

Here is what is changed :

```
class PostImage(models.Model):
# post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='image', null=True)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='image', null=True)
image = ProcessedImageField(verbose_name=_('image'), storage=post_image_storage,
                            upload_to=upload_to_post_image_directory,
                            width_field='width',
                            height_field='height',
                            blank=False, null=True, format='JPEG', options={'quality': 80},
```

The logs of docker-compose :

```html
my-api        | Traceback (most recent call last):
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
my-api        |     response = get_response(request)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
my-api        |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
my-api        |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
my-api        |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
my-api        |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
my-api        |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
my-api        |     raise exc
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
my-api        |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
my-api        |   File "/opt/my-api-core/my_posts/views/posts/views.py", line 55, in get
my-api        |     return self.get_posts_for_authenticated_user(request)
my-api        |   File "/opt/my-api-core/my_posts/views/posts/views.py", line 92, in get_posts_for_authenticated_user
my-api        |     post_serializer_data = AuthenticatedUserPostSerializer(posts, many=True, context={"request": request}).data
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 768, in data
my-api        |     ret = super().data
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
my-api        |     self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
my-api        |     return [
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
my-api        |     self._fetch_all()
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 273, in _fetch_all
my-api        |     return self._no_monkey._fetch_all(self)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
my-api        |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
my-api        |     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
my-api        |     sql, params = self.as_sql()
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 507, in as_sql
my-api        |     extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 55, in pre_sql_setup
my-api        |     self.setup_query()
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 46, in setup_query
my-api        |     self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 227, in get_select
my-api        |     cols = self.get_default_columns()
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 671, in get_default_columns
my-api        |     only_load = self.deferred_to_columns()
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1096, in deferred_to_columns
my-api        |     self.query.deferred_to_data(columns, self.query.get_loaded_field_names_cb)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 754, in deferred_to_data
my-api        |     callback(target, model, values)
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2179, in get_loaded_field_names_cb
my-api        |     target[model] = {f.attname for f in fields}
my-api        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2179, in <setcomp>
my-api        |     target[model] = {f.attname for f in fields}
my-api        | AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'
django.server ERROR    "GET /api/posts/?count=10& HTTP/1.1" 500 195670
```

Based on the above logs, the function causing the error :

```html
def get_posts_for_authenticated_user(self, request):
        query_params = request.query_params.dict()
        normalize_list_value_in_request_data('circle_id', query_params)
        normalize_list_value_in_request_data('list_id', query_params)

        serializer = GetPostsSerializer(data=query_params)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.validated_data

        circles_ids = data.get('circle_id')
        lists_ids = data.get('list_id')
        max_id = data.get('max_id')
        min_id = data.get('min_id')
        count = data.get('count', 10)
        username = data.get('username')

        user = request.user

        if username:
            if username == user.username:
                posts = user.get_posts(max_id=max_id)
            else:
                posts = user.get_posts_for_user_with_username(username, max_id=max_id, min_id=min_id)
        else:
            posts = user.get_timeline_posts(
                circles_ids=circles_ids,
                lists_ids=lists_ids,
                max_id=max_id,
                min_id=min_id,
                count=count
            )

        posts = posts.order_by('-id')[:count]

        post_serializer_data = AuthenticatedUserPostSerializer(posts, many=True, context={"request": request}).data

        return Response(post_serializer_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

What I have tried :

1.Changed the order_by() from

```
posts = posts.order_by('-id')[:count]
```

to

```
posts = posts.order_by('-created')[:count]
```

since count was mentioned in the docker logs. But still getting the said error.

2.I even tried clearing the database using the flush command. Recreated the docker containers. Error persists.

Comment: in your database you still have record related to MTM? if you have then delete these records and create again

Comment: @TanveerAhmad. reset the db and error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'`: that should mean that Django tries to access a field attribute that does not exist on a related model.
That error often occurs after changing relationships in models, as you did by changing a `OneToOneField` to a `ForeignKey`. (a bit as in "[How to Update Django Model Relationship only with Foreign Key Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72067599/6309)", even though the focus is on how to update a foreign key relationship in a Django model by directly using the primary key of the related model, rather than fetching the entire related model instance).

When you switch from a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) to a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), Django treats this relationship differently. The `ManyToOneRel` object is an internal Django construct representing the reverse relation from `Post` to `PostImage`.

Since the error is occurring during serialization, make sure `AuthenticatedUserPostSerializer` correctly handles the `post` field. If the serializer attempts to access a non-existent attribute on the `post` field, it could cause this error. Look for any part of the serializer that might be treating `post.image` as a single instance rather than a set of instances.

You have `related_name='image'` in your `ForeignKey`. That means that, on the `Post` model, Django expects `post.image` to return multiple `PostImage` instances. If anywhere in your code (or serializers) you are treating `post.image` as a single instance (as it was with a `OneToOneField`), it would cause an error. You might need to adjust this logic or change the `related_name` to something like `'images'` to reflect the multiple instances.

The `related_name='image'` in your `ForeignKey` should now reflect that `post.image` will return a queryset of `PostImage` instances, not a single instance. Consider changing it to `'images'` to better represent the relationship.

```py
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images', null=True)
    ...
```

After changing field types, make sure your database schema is updated correctly with Django migrations. Sometimes, inconsistencies between the model and the database can lead to unexpected errors.

Finally, add debugging information in the `get_posts_for_authenticated_user` method to inspect the `posts` query.

```py
def get_posts_for_authenticated_user(self, request):
    ...
    posts = posts.order_by('-id')[:count]

    # Debugging: Print or log the query
    print("DEBUG: posts query", posts.query)

    post_serializer_data = AuthenticatedUserPostSerializer(posts, many=True, context={"request": request}).data

    return Response(post_serializer_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

These debugging statements will help you understand what is happening at the database query level. Keep an eye on your console or logs to see the output.

---

> My objective is to allow model `PostImage` to allow for multiple images upload and link it to a Post. e.g. A single blog post having multiple images.
>
> Correct me if I am wrong, changing the `related_name` to '`images`' with a `ForeignKey` to `Post` will allow for multiple instances of `PostImages`?
> Because I do have code logic with the field '`image`' inside `post` as you rightly mentioned. There is also a `image = ProcessedImageField` right below where I define the `ForeignKey`.
>
> As a note just before debugging, I just changed '`image`' to 'images' as you mentioned and ran a GET request after running migrations. I now get : FieldDoesNotExist: Post has no field named 'image'

The `related_name` attribute in a `ForeignKey` relationship specifies the name to use for the reverse relation from the related model back to your model. In your case, by setting `related_name='images'` in the `PostImage` model, you are telling Django to use `images` to access related `PostImage` instances from a `Post` instance.
So, after this change, on any `Post` object, you can access its related `PostImage` objects using `post.images.all()`.

Yes, changing to a ForeignKey and using `related_name='images'` will indeed allow multiple instances of `PostImage` to be associated with a single `Post`. That is the correct approach for your use case where a blog post may have multiple images.

The error `FieldDoesNotExist: Post has no field named 'image'` occurs because, in your views or serializers, you are likely still accessing `image` directly on a `Post` object. After the change in your model, you should update your code to use `images`.
Wherever you were accessing `post.image`, you should now use `post.images.all()` to get a queryset of all related `PostImage` objects.

Update any views, serializers, or other parts of your code that previously relied on `post.image`. For serialization, if you need to include images in your `Post` serializer, you might use a nested serializer for `PostImage`.

Your serializer could be:

```py
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ['image', ...]  # Include other fields as needed

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'images', ...]  # Other Post fields
```

Run migrations again after any model change:

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. My objective is to allow model PostImage to allow for multiple images upload and link it to a Post. e.g. A single blog post having multiple images. Correct me if im wrong, changing the related_name to 'images' with a ForeignKey to Post will allow for multiple instances of PostImages ? Because I do have code logic with the field 'image' inside post as you rightly mentioned. There is also a image = ProcessedImageField right below where I define the ForeignKey.

Comment: As a note just before debugging, I just changed 'image' to 'images' as you mentioned and ran a GET request after running migrations. I now get : FieldDoesNotExist: Post has no field named 'image'

Comment: Hi again. I'm still figuring out where the problem is in the serializers. Also did as you suggested. Could you kindly check my earlier comment

Comment: Could we continue this discussion in chat. Could have your 10 mins ?

Comment: @Earthling Sure: add another comment, and I will be able to invite you to a chat room.

Comment: Hello. Lets chat.

Comment: @Earthling Not enough comments yet...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256371/discussion-between-vonc-and-earthling).